# How to fit a Keras model on multiple cores of a CPU?

Tags: python, keras, parallel-processing, cpu

I'm trying to fit a `Keras` model on several cores of my CPU. I've done several researches concerning that and I tried to set a tensorflow backend that can handle several cores :

```
session_conf =
tensorflow.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=32,inter_op_parallelism_threads=32,log_device_placement=True)
tensorflow.set_random_seed(1)
keras.backend.set_session(tensorflow.Session(graph=tensorflow.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf))
```

I tried to use it in this context :

```
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error',metrics=['acc'])  
    trained=False
    if(trained==False):
        compteur=600
        while(compteur>0):
            print("epoch :" + str(compteur))
            hist=model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs = 1, batch_size = 50)  
            compteur=compteur-1
            if(hist.history['loss'][-1]<0.0005):
                break
    else:
        model = load_model('mode_trained_12h.h5')
```

But it does not seem to work (the 64 cores CPU is only 3* faster than my cheap local CPU). Any idea on how to solve that ? Am I using `keras` the right way for that ?

Thanks

Julien

Comment: You should use a much larger batch size, this will increase performance

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My training set is composed of 700 reshaped arrays for my LSTM, do you think I could go over 50 samples per batch ?

Comment: I don't see why not. Just try.

Comment: Just an aside, take a look at using the [`EarlyStopping` callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping) for managing your inner loop there. It basically takes care of checking some metric at each epoch and stopping if the metric meets certain criteria. A common use is to stop if your validation loss fails to improve for some number of epochs. It's easy to use and cleans up your training loop code a bit.

Comment: thanks. using a larger batch size increased the speed of my algorithm. I'm going to use the EarlyStopping callback as well, I think it can improve my code.